# Fastest way to take 2D input and sort it simultaneously Row wise

Tags: c++, sorting

I need a way in Which I can take the Input in a 2d array and sort it row wise in one of the fastest way . I tried taking Input and Sort it simultaneously using `Insertion Sort`. The Second thing I used is i took a `multimap` individually for a row and inserted with key value as the value i want and mapped value relates to that key as some Dummy value . Since map sorts key while Inserting It could be the one way I thought .

The below code is for making sure that 1 row in my 2D has its element sorted in
multimap. Basically you can say that I dont want to use a 2D structure at all as I 
will use these rows individually one by one and hence can be considered as 1D array.
I also want they they gets rearranged While reading the Input , so i dont have to
extra opeartions for doing them.

```
for(long int j=1;j<=number_in_group;j++)
{
   cin >> arrival_time;
   arrival_map.insert(pair<long int, long int>(arrival_time,1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an `STL std::priority_queue`? The output is guaranteed to be sorted, and if you polarize the inputs to be 2-D objects (that contain a row number for example) you're queue will build literally perfectly. At that point simply slurp the number off the queue in batches of 'n' where 'n' is your row size and each one will be sorted correctly. You will need a element type that encodes both the value AND the row in your priority queue, and sorts biased to the row # first, then then value. Your example uses `long int` as the data type for your values. Assuming your rows are no larger than the size of a system unsigned int:

```
class Element
{
public:
   Element(unsigned int row, long int val)
      : myrow(row), myval(val)
   {};

   bool operator <(const Element& elem)
   {
      return (myrow < elem.myrow || 
             (myrow == elem.myrow && myval < elem.myvel);
   }

   unsigned int myrow;
   long int myval;
};


typedef std::priority_queue<Element> MyQueue;
```

Note: this takes advantage of the priority queue's default comparison operator invoking `std::less<>`, which simply compares the items using the item-defined `operator <()`. Once you have this simply push your matrix into the queue, incrementing the row index as you switch to the next row.

MyQueue mq;

```
mq.push_back(Element(1,100));
mq.push_back(Element(1,99));
mq.push_back(Element(2,100));
mq.push_back(Element(2,101));
```

Popping the queue when finished will result in the following sequence:
99
100
100
101

Which I hope is what you want. Finally, please forgive the syntax errors and/or missing junk, as I just blasted this on the fly and have no compiler to check it against. Gotta love web cafes.

Comment: Why does the compiler tell me No Match For operator <(operand types are ‘const VP’ and ‘const VP’)? I do have one.